# Retrieving data from Firebase Web

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Been trying multiple different ways to get this to work. The aim is to have a welcome box that doesn't appear if the user has seen it before. If the Active field in my database shows a 1 the welcome div should not be visible.

```
document.onload = function() {
  var active
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var uid;

  if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
  }

  firebase.database().ref("Users/" + uid + '/Active').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var active = childSnapshot.val();
      if (active = 1) {
        document.getElementById("welcome").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("title").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("text").style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  });
};
```

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: Notice single `=` in `if (active = 1)`. Why not `if (active == 1)` ? :)

Comment: Thanks, I've made the change. Although something is still not working

Comment: You may also want to adopt a strategy of 3 states - 1) Loading.... 2) Welcome 3) No Welcome but done loading. This way the momentary display of welcome will not be seen.

Comment: Please define what is `something is still not working`.

Comment: Also, if `welcome` is the parent container of `box`, `title` and `text`, then you only need to hide it, and not the others.

Comment: Well the welcome box is still displaying, even though the current user has been active before

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the property of the object - childSnapshot.val().active.

Respectfully, you're going about it backwards.  If the user is not in the database, you want to show the welcome card.  If the user is in the database, they've probably already interacted with the app and seen the welcome card.

The welcome card should be hidden by CSS `display: none` so it does not blink or show at all on page load.

Use a boolean, native `true` or `false` (notice no quotes around the word) rather than a 1 or 0, in my opinion.  Initialize `var showWelcomeCard = false` at the top of your script.

Once you determine that you should show the welcome card, show it; not the other way around.

Lastly don't assume they don't want to see the welcome/start card again.  Offer them a choice.  A checkbox saying "Don't show this again".  So, change the property from `active` to `showWelcomeCard`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I should have mentioned that the welcome box appears the first time they log in so that they can provide a display name and a pathway as the user account is created by an administrator. The user can edit this later on in the settings. But this means the user is already in the database before they have seen the welcome box?